# Moving select file types to new directory based on dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I  am trying to move specific filetypes to a new directory based on a nested dictionary.

**For example**, (to separate video and photo files) move media files defined in `config[key1][other_file]` to `OTHERMEDIA` for each camera models in their respective folders:

```
001__=d5
    OTHERMEDIA                                   #move files to here
    IMAGES
        [mix of mediafiles in subdirectories]    #move files from here
002__=alpha9
    OTHERMEDIA                                   #move files to here
    IMAGES
        [mix of mediafiles in subdirectories]    #move files from here
```

**Code** gives `shutil.move(os.path.join(root,files), os.path.join(destinationpath,files))`. What I am doing wrong?

```
import shutil
import os
config = {
    'd5': {},
    'alpha9': {},
    'g7': {},
}
config['d5']['other_file'] = ('avi', 'AVI')
config['alpha9']['other_file'] = ('jpg', 'JPG')
config['g7']['other_file'] = ('mp4', 'MP4')

destinationpath = 'OTHERMEDIA'
root = os.getcwd()
for camID in config:
    for dir in next(os.walk(root))[1]:
        if dir.endswith(camID):
            for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(root, dir)):
                for f in files:
                    if any([f.lower().endswith(x) for x in config[camID]["other_file"]]):
                        os.path.join(path, f). files, os.path.join(destinationpath,files)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `os.path.join(path, files)` when you should be doing `os.path.join(path, f)`. `files` is the entire iterable; `f` is the specific file.

Also, as an aside, since you're looking at `f.lower()`, you don't need to compare it with the capitalized versions of the file extensions.

Comment: updated as suggested (see OP). still error: `line 20, in <module>
    os.path.join(path, f). files, os.path.join(destinationpath,files)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'files'`

Comment: There's a syntax error there. I would write `shutil.move(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(destinationpath, f))` for the last line.

Comment: bottom line as `shutil.move(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(destinationpath, f))`. error msg: in `\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shutil.py` and many other error